# Update XML node value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need to update the GroupID field to a 0.  I have figured out how to retrieve the value, I am now running into problems updating it.

Any help would ge great!

```
<ProblemProfile>
  <GroupID>-1</GroupID>
  <LayoutID>1</LayoutID>
  <MyQueries>false</MyQueries>
</ProblemProfile>

Declare @Result xml
set @Result = convert(xml,(select ProfileXML from profiles where id = 23))

SELECT x.value('.', 'int') ID
FROM @Result.nodes('/ProblemProfile/GroupID') as R(x)
```

**Update**

What I need to do now is update every single row's GroupID that has the value of 'foo'

```
declare @foo int
set @foo = -1

UPDATE  profiles
SET  ProfileXML.modify('replace value of (/ProblemProfile/GroupID/text())[1] with "0"')
WHERE  ProfileXML.value('(/ProblemProfile/GroupID)[1]', 'int') = @foo
```

This is only updating the first row that meets this criteria.  How would I update every row?

***Update 2***
That statement works.  Turns out the database structure for the first node can be different.  A simple //GroupID...etc updated every row.   It is always the stupid little things that trip us up haha.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
UPDATE 
   dbo.profiles
SET 
   ProfileXML.modify('replace value of (/ProblemProfile/GroupID/text())[1] with "0"')
WHERE
   id = 23
```

Check out this article on [SQL Server 2005 XQuery and XML-DML](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19491/SQL-Server-2005-XQuery-and-XMLDML--Part-1.htm) for more details on what you can do with the `.modify` keyword (insert, delete, replace etc.).

Marc

PS: In order to get the value, it would be a lot easier to do just this:

```
SELECT ProfileXML.value('(/ProblemProfile/GroupID)[1]', 'int') as ID
FROM dbo.profiles
WHERE id = 23
```

(unless of course you need the XML as a SQL variable for something else later on)

Comment: Actually the use of nodes() and values() is a good practice. In this case doesn't make any difference, but if multiple columns are quested is better to use nodes(): "The combination of the nodes() and value() methods can be more efficient in generating the rowset when it has several columns" http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187508(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: @Remus: yes, good point - if you need several values, using nodes() makes total sense, I agree.

Comment: Excellent. just what I need.

Comment: What if the node is a dropdownlist, how can  I change the selected index? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but how to replace value of a node with its current value + some extra text? I googled and found zero examples? Any clue where to look?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to change the text inside element

```
UPDATE [TableName]
   SET  
      [fieldName].modify('replace value of (root/elementName/text())[1] with "wBob"')
GO
```