# INSERT data into a column of XML datatype

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Server database with a column of type `XML`. I've been looking about for ways to populate it using an `INSERT` query / stored procedure from asp.net.

So far all I can find is ways to get (`SELECT`) the XML data and execute an `SqlDataReader` / `XMLReader` (such as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/zh9a9y6s.aspx) example)

How can I go about populating the column from ASP.NET? The xml will look something like the following:

```
<remarks>
    <remark>
        <author>...</author>
        <date>...</date>
        <content>...</content>
    </remark>
    <remark>
        <author>...</author>
        <date>...</date>
        <content>...</content>
    </remark>
</remarks>
```

The 'content' will be entered by a user in a textbox, and the other columns will be populated using `DateTime.Now()` and `User.Identity.Name`.

I am looking to be able to:

1. Enter a first remark into an empty XML column.
2. Enter additional remarks at a later time.

Can this be done? I can't manage to find any information on this.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for INSERT

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(idCol,xmlCol)
values(1,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<remarks>
    <remark>
        <author>...</author>
        <date>...</date>
        <content>...</content>
    </remark>
    <remark>
        <author>...</author>
        <date>...</date>
        <content>...</content>
    </remark>
</remarks>')
```

For UPDATE, I won't give a better answer than https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440688/1236044