# How can I update a specific node in a xml column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xquery, xquery-sql

I have the following data stored in my table [fixed_width_export_specification_t][specification_xml]'

```
<fixed_width_metadata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <fixed_width_metadata_row>
    <rowtype>sys_header</rowtype>
    <dbname>sys_nm_label</dbname>
    <width>56</width>
    <fillleftright>right</fillleftright>
  </fixed_width_metadata_row>
  <fixed_width_metadata_row>
    <rowtype>remit1</rowtype>
    <dbname>remit_column1</dbname>
    <width>32</width>
    <fillleftright>right</fillleftright>
  </fixed_width_metadata_row>
</fixed_width_metadata>
```

I want to update the width where rowtype is equal to remit1 and dbname is equal to remit_column1 from 32 to 61

I played around with the diffrent xqueries to na avail. I don't know how to isolate the element that I want namely width and to then subsequenly update its value.

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update XML node value in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440666/update-xml-node-value-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
update fixed_width_export_specification_t
set specification_xml.modify
  ('replace value of (/fixed_width_metadata/
                        fixed_width_metadata_row
                         [rowtype = "remit1" and dbname = "remit_column1"]/
                          width/text())[1] 
      with 61 ')
```