# Update(Replace partcial value) XML Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

I have an XML column in my Table and i wanted to replace particular text wherever it appear in that column with a new text. Here is the xml structure,

```
<Story>
 <StoryNonText>
  <NonText>
   <ImageID>1</ImageID>
   <Src>http://staging.xyz.com/FolderName/1.png</Src>
  </NonText>
  <NonText>
   <ImageID>2</ImageID>
   <Src>http://staging.xyz.com/FolderName/2.png</Src>
  </NonText>
 </StoryNonText>
</Story>
```

In the above XML I wanted to replace all the `<Src>` values having **http://staging.xyz.com/** to **http://production.xyz.com/**. Please guide me how i can do this!

Comment: Is it unsave to do `REPLACE ( yourcolumn, 'http://staging.xyz.com/' , 'http://production.xyz.com/' )` on this column?

Comment: I think it may be safe for this exercise, but generally speaking it may be not good solution. That value can be appeared in other places within XML document.

Comment: Then take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1440688/2074825

Comment: @EdwinStoteler how can i use REPLACE function on xml column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **Replace()** function as below:

```
Update TableName
SET
ColumnName=replace(CAST(ColumnName AS VARCHAR(8000)),'<Src>http://staging.xyz.com/','<Src>http://production.xyz.com/')
```

Comment: Alot saver then my comment, but what if the `<src>` tag has attributes. Or sometimes there is a space after the tag?

Comment: if attributes there, it predefined so can adjust in update statement

Comment: @SandipPatel Thanks, It seems simpler as it look like. let me try on this.

Answer (score 5):

With a little help from a couple of XML functions you can do this in a loop.
The loop is necessary since `replace value of` can only replace one value at a time. This code assumes the URL is located first in the node and not embedded in text anywhere.

```sql
declare @T table(X xml);

insert into @T(X) values('<Story>
 <StoryNonText>
  <NonText>
   <ImageID>1</ImageID>
   <Src>http://staging.xyz.com/FolderName/1.png</Src>
  </NonText>
  <NonText>
   <ImageID>2</ImageID>
   <Src>http://staging.xyz.com/FolderName/2.png</Src>
  </NonText>
 </StoryNonText>
</Story> ');

declare @FromURL nvarchar(100);
declare @ToURL nvarchar(100);

set @FromURL = 'http://staging.xyz.com/';
set @ToURL = 'http://production.xyz.com/';

while 1 = 1
begin
  update @T
  set X.modify('replace value of (//*/text()[contains(., sql:variable("@FromURL"))])[1] 
               with concat(sql:variable("@ToURL"), substring((//*/text()[contains(., sql:variable("@FromURL"))])[1], string-length(sql:variable("@FromURL"))+1))')
  where X.exist('//*/text()[contains(., sql:variable("@FromURL"))]') = 1;

  if @@rowcount = 0
    break;
end;

select *
from @T
```

[replace value of (XML DML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx)
[concat Function (XQuery)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190972.aspx)
[contains Function (XQuery)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178026.aspx)
[string-length Function (XQuery)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188700.aspx)
[sql:variable() Function (XQuery)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mikael. How can I use this for multiple rows?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo this is for multiple rows- Just replace the table variable `@T` in my code with your real table.

Comment: In my case, I add an error with text(), so I specified the key-value directly:
```UPDATE [svc].[blob]
      SET props.modify('replace value of (/root/item[key="YOUR_KEY"]/value[contains(., sql:variable("@FromURL"))])[1] 
                   with concat(sql:variable("@ToURL"), substring((/root/item[key="YOUR_KEY"]/value[contains(., sql:variable("@FromURL"))])[1], string-length(sql:variable("@FromURL"))+1))')
      where props.exist('/root/item[key="YOUR_KEY"]/value[contains(., sql:variable("@FromURL"))]') = 1;```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that.

The first way is to add a WHILE loop. Inside a loop, you search (CHARINDEX) for a position of first  tag and first  tag. Then, knowing the start and end positions, replace the value. Then on the next iteration you search again, but change starting position in CHARINDEX() function

The second way is to use SELECT ... FROM OPENXML   +  EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument